# ORACLE PL/SQL : How to pass an exception into a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to pass exception into a procedure to call "raise" after doing some actions to process exception. So that the outer code block will get the exact exception that was raised

Something like this:

```
begin
    ...
exception
    when others then
        error_handler( err );
end;

procedure error_handler ( err ) is
begin
    /*
        here some code to handle and log the exception...
    */

    raise err;
end;
```

Or the only way is to pass SQLCODE and SQLERRM into the procedure and later call raise_application_error( SQLCODE, SQLERRM )?

Comment: AFAIK, if you just call `RAISE;` you re-raise the exception that occured last. That means you don't have to pass the exception.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner PLS-00367: a RAISE statement with no exception name must be inside an exception handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you're asking.

Sample log table:

```
SQL> create table err_log
  2    (program    varchar2(30),
  3     datum      date,
  4     sqlcode    number
  5    );

Table created.
```

Logging procedure should be an autonomous transaction so that you could `commit` in it, without affecting main transaction.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure error_handler
  2    (p_program in varchar2, p_sqlcode in number)
  3  is
  4    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  5  begin
  6    insert into err_log (program, datum, sqlcode)
  7      values (p_program, sysdate, p_sqlcode);
  8    commit;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

Another procedure (whose execution you're logging); it'll raise *division by zero*. See lines #8 and #9 which call the logging procedure and then just re-raise the error:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is
  2    l_program varchar2(30) := 'P_TEST';
  3    l_value   number;
  4  begin
  5    l_value := 1 / 0;
  6  exception
  7    when others then
  8      error_handler(l_program, sqlcode);
  9      raise;
 10  end p_test;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

OK, everything is set. Let's try it:

```
SQL> exec p_test;
BEGIN p_test; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero         --> this is result of RAISE in line #9
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 9
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Log table contents:

```
SQL> select * from err_log;

PROGRAM                        DATUM                  SQLCODE
------------------------------ ------------------- ----------
P_TEST                         01.11.2022 11:13:31      -1476

SQL>
```

---

You asked, literally:

> How to pass an exception into a procedure?

You can't, as far as I can tell:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure error_handler_text
  2    (p_err in exception)                  --> if this is what you asked
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    null;
  6  end;
  7  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE ERROR_HANDLER_TEXT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/13     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one
         of the following:
         out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         table columns long double ref char standard time timestamp
         interval date binary national character nchar
         The symbol "<an identifier> was inserted before "EXCEPTION" to
         continue.

SQL>
```

Comment: My desire is to put all the error-handling code in one procedure (including "rise"). Just to avoid repeating this "rise" in every single exception block. But if that's not possible, your suggestion is great.

Comment: That's not possible, because RAISE is valid only in EXCEPTION handling section. But, to get into that section, there must be an error you'd have to raise first. As you can't pass exception itself, there's nothing to raise so you can't get into EXCEPTION so ... no, that won't work. On the other hand, a tiny little word RAISE in every procedure you have really isn't that much so that you should worry about *avoiding* it, I think.